# Chemical equilibrium for distinguishable reactant particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, equilibrium, chemical-potential

Denote the partition function of a single particle by $\zeta$. The particles of one type of reactant in a chemical reaction are normally indistinguishable. The partition function of $n$ number of a single reactant is $\frac{\zeta^n}{n!}$.
Suppose now the particles are all distinct. The corresponding partition function should be $\zeta^n$. Suppose there is a chemical reaction composed of these all-distinguishable particles. The Gibbs free energy
$$F = -kT \sum_{i=1}^m n_i\ln \zeta_i.$$
The infinitesimal change in $F$ is
$$-\beta dF=\sum_i dn_i \ln \zeta_i=du\sum_i b_i \ln \zeta_i$$
for some variable $u$ where $b_i$ is the reactant ratio. It seems unlike the usual chemical reaction, the macroscopic chemical equilibrium is reached only when the microscopic reaction ratio satisfies this condition and the equilibrium is independent of the concentration of each reactant. Is this derivation correct? Is there an actual example of this kind of reaction -- maybe Fermionic (chemical) reaction?

Comment: Usually within a reactant the particles are indistinguishable. At least, this is certainly the case for fermions.

Comment: @LPZ: Are you trying to say "bosons" instead of "fermions"?

Comment: Both fermions and bosons are indistinguishable. This is the motivation behind second quantization. Perhaps you are confusing distinguishability with the exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but the applicability to fermions and bosons is not. More generally, the classical distinguishable case has little use.

For each reactant, you are considering the canonical ensemble, i.e. fixed total number of particles. You basically use for indistinguishable particles:
$$
\zeta^{(N)} = \frac{\zeta^N}{N!} \\
F = -k_BTN\ln\frac\zeta N
$$
and distinguishable particles:
$$
\zeta^{(N)} = \zeta^N \\
F = -k_BTN\ln\zeta
$$
with $\zeta:= \zeta^{(1)}$, which is independent of $N$. For example for a gas in a box:
$$
\zeta = \frac V{(2\pi\beta)^{3/2}}
$$
with $\beta = \frac1{k_BT}$. You need to use the indistinguishable formula or else you loose extensivity (Gibbs' paradox).

This does not work anymore for bosons and fermions. There is not simple formula for relating $\zeta^{(N)}$ to $\zeta$ because of statistics. The usual approach is to rather use the grand canonical ensemble. Take for example nonrelativistic, 3D, massive particles in a box of volume $V$. In the following, I will set $m=k_B=1$.

For bosons (above the condensation temperature), the free energy is ($z$ is the fugacity $z:= e^{\beta \mu}$, which is solved in terms of $N$ using the second equation):
$$
F = -\frac {TV}{(2\pi\beta)^{3/2}}[Li_{5/2}(z)+\ln zLi_{3/2}(z)]\\
N = \frac V{(2\pi\beta)^{3/2}}Li_{3/2}(z)
$$
As you can see, $F$ is not just proportional to $N$, it depends in an intricate manner with the density $n=N/V$. However you still have extensivity. Notice that at high temperature, you recover the indistinguishable classical gas.

For fermions, the free energy is:
$$
F = \frac {TV}{(2\pi\beta)^{3/2}}[Li_{5/2}(-z)+\ln zLi_{3/2}(-z)]\\
N = -\frac V{(2\pi\beta)^{3/2}}Li_{3/2}(-z)
$$
The same remarks apply.

Your reasoning can be modified to apply in general. You just need to write for individual reactants:
$$
F = \sum F_i\\
dF = \sum \mu_idN_i
$$
and for a chemical reaction of fixed stoichiometry:
$$
dN_i = \nu_id\xi
$$
so:
$$
dF = \left(\sum \mu_i\nu_i\right)d\xi
$$
and you recover the action mass law:
$$
\sum \mu_i\nu_i = 0
$$

Your approach amounts to singling out the $N_i$ dependencies. For indistinguishable particles (with $\zeta_i$ independent from $N_i$):
$$
\mu_i = \ln\frac{\zeta_i}{N_i}-1
$$
Whereas for distinguishable particles (which is rarely applicable):
$$
\mu_i = \ln\zeta_i
$$

For quantum gases, you'll need to solve for the fugacity using the second equations and then invert fugacity to get the chemical potential.

Hope this helps.